# Xcode IB Can't Read Archive?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I just created a new project from a template and when I try to build the project I get a "Could not read archive" error for each nib file from the compiler. I did some Googling but could not find an explanation or steps to debug. Has anyone run into this error before or can someone explain what it means?

When I try to open the nibs with Interface Builder I get the same error in a pop up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an idiot. Project name included an ampersand '&' character. Reread the Nimble Kit [Coding Examples](http://write2grow.org/nimblekit/NimbleKit_Community_Documentation/Coding_Examples.html). and saw the little warning against using special characters "especially '&'" near be bottom of the Xcode compiling error segment in order to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bunch of things that never worked. I finally solved this issue by simply deleting the item out of XCode (just remove the reference..DO NOT..I REPEAT..DO NOT move it to the trash!!). Then, Add the file back into the project by Selecting "File" - "Add Files" or right clicking some folder in the Folder Navigator view and selecting "Add Files". I then cleaned the project just to be on the safe side and after that I built the project and it worked!

Comment: I had that problem today. For me it turned out to be a result of a bad SCM merge. So if all else fails, open the XIB with text editor and look for merge markers.